# Update Data using entity Frame in C# form

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am a beginner in entity framework. I want to update data by using entity framework C# but having this error all the time

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

I am Using Visual Studio 2013

```
namespace Entity_FrameWork
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Beta_DatabaseEntities db = new Beta_DatabaseEntities();
        table1 tb = new table1();
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public int Salary;

        public void Entry()
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt16(id.Text);
            Name = name.Text;
            //Salary = Convert.ToInt32(salary.Text);
            tb.Id = ID;
            tb.Name = Name;
            //tb.Salary = Salary;
        }

        private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Entry();
            db.Entry(tb).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("UPDATED");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beta_DatabaseEntities db = new Beta_DatabaseEntities();  Which taable of this EDMX you are trying to update?    ID = Convert.ToInt16(id.Text); where is this id varoiable variable and is it assigned?

Comment: i have only one table named table1 in my database named Beta_DatabaseEntities... well id is a name of textBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace Entity_FrameWork
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Beta_DatabaseEntities db = new Beta_DatabaseEntities();
        table1 tb = new table1();
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public int Salary;

        public void Entry()
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt16(id.Text);
            Name = name.Text;
            //Salary = Convert.ToInt32(salary.Text);
            tb.Id = ID;
            tb.Name = Name;
            //tb.Salary = Salary;
        }

        private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {tb=db.Tables.where(x=>x.id==1).firstOrDefault();
            Entry();
            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("UPDATED");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow shijo! We encourage learning, so instead of just posting code, would you also explain what, why and how it solves the problem? Thanks!